# What are Microsoft Edge *.etl Files, and how did I end up with one that's 45GB

Tags: disk-space, microsoft-edge

My computer has been running low on disk space.

I ran WinDirStat to try and dig into the details of what was taking up so much space.

Very surprised to find a massive, 45GB `*.etl` file sitting in the following location:

> C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC#!001\Temp\Microsoft\F12\perftools\visualprofiler\491395C5-91E3-4900-8CEB-D97031EDC82C

The file has a name similar to:

> IEEtwSession.Usr-28C8-EDB3809C-E13A-4A06-BF01-DF21A169C85C.etl

Is this the data store for the Edge F12 tools profiler?

Comment: [Client-Side Logging and Diagnostics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg195661(v=ocs.14).aspx) feel free to delete them.  They are client logs connected to Windows event trace logs.  I realize the article is about Lync but it has the description of the file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ETL files are **E**vent **T**racing for Windows **L**og. [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (ETW) was added in Windows 2000 and today Microsoft uses it to measure performance of Windows and its components.

It looks like the F12 Developer Tools of Edge/IE created the files. If you don't care of any perf issues of Edge, delete them.

Comment: Thanks - I think you have just confirmed what I was suspecting.  I find it interesting that an ETL file is left to grow to an enormous size like that, especially considering that I didn't actively set out to capture any event tracing detail.